# Facebook PHP SDK: OAuthException: (#200) Feed story publishing is disabled for this application

Tags: php, facebook

Having a bit of an issue with the Facebook PHP SDK at the moment

I have an app that basically asks a user to authenticate themselves via the SDK, loads up the auth dialog asking for permissions to post as the user, and then brings up a textbox with some pre-filled text that the user can alter as needed, which then posts to the users feed.

This has been working fine, however today I have received a developer alert saying that the app is in violation of platform policies due to creating a negative experience.

Having looked in insights though, there is no spam alerts and no messages about users blocking the apps, but when looking in my error logs, I have noted that I am getting this error message:

OAuthException: (#200) Feed story publishing is disabled for this application.

I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong - I have passed publish_actions into the scope and the user gets the option during authentication, with my actual call being:

```
$attachment =  array(
    'message' => stripslashes($_POST['message']),
    'link'=> REDIRECT_URL,
    'picture'=>SEND_TO_FRIENDS_IMAGE,
    'description'=>SHARE_DESCRIPTION,
    'name'=>SHARE_TITLE,
    'caption'=>SHARE_CAPTION
); 
try{
    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post',$attachment);
}catch(Exception $e){
    error_log($e);
}
```

Which is a block of code that has worked fine for me for a long time.

I was just wondering if anyone had any experience with the error I received, both from the Facebook notification or from the OAuth response

Thanks